# adding colors to geom_point() in ggplot2 with a box plot overlay

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the colors of the points to reflect the "fluorophore" column in my data (either red, green, or amber).  However, whenever I do this manually using scale_color_manual, it changes the boxplot to be each individual fluorophore color as well.  I want the boxplot to be for each well number, but the data points to be colored according to fluorophore!

```
ggplot(sample1_50kreg, aes(x = well_number, y = cq)) +
geom_boxplot() +
geom_point(color = "purple", alpha = 0.5) +
theme_bw()
```

[[image]]

```
ggplot(sample1_50kreg, aes(x = well_number, y = cq, color=fluorophore)) +
geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
geom_boxplot () +
theme_bw() +
scale_color_manual(breaks = c("red", "green", "amber"),
                 values = c("gold", "green", "red"))
```

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

```
sample1_50kreg <- as.factor(sample1_50kreg$fluorophore)
```

and re-run your script
check: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually

Comment: I want the points to be colored according to fluorophore, but i want the box plot to not be colored, and not according to fluorophore, just well number (x axis).  I don't think as.factor is going to change that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
ggplot(sample1_50kreg, aes(x = well_number, y = cq)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point (aes(color = fluorophore)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("red", "green", "amber"),
                   values = c("gold", "green", "red"))
```